# Renaming a variable can affect many other files

Tags: intellij-idea, rename

Just something I'm curious about. Here's what I do:

1. I have a class with a member(`type`) who I want to rename to `alertType`, for example.
2. I right click the member, `Refactor->Rename..` and enter the new name.
3. I'm prompted if I want to rename getters and setter too, I say yes.
4. IntelliJ scans my whole project and gives me the list of changes
5. The default refactoring is so broad, it renames any variable called `type`, or many html tags.
6. I know I can exclude/remove these refactorings, but if I forget to do that, it breaks my codebase and I have to revert, which is a bit tedious.

[image]

My question is, is there a way to change the default rename behaviour to only include the `Field to be renamed` and `References in code to parameter, method` refactorings? I don't think I would ever want the dynamic and comment/string replacements- I'm just trying to quickly rename a single variable.

Comment: Your step #5 sounds completely off to me.  Refactoring a single field `type` should not cause all variables called `type` to be refactored.

Comment: I couldn'r reproduce your case. Seems you have "Search in comments and strings" and "Search for text occurences" options enabled in refactor dialog.

Comment: @y.bedrov where can I find that dialog? I suppose that is what I'm looking for, is where those options are.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok, in fairness, it is not affecting any java variables- it is just fragments of html and jsp and other text files. For example, it is wanting to change a line `<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>` in an `.md` file.

Comment: That's really weird...I'd ask for a repro, but obviously that can't really be given here.

Comment: Does this happen with all refactors, or just when refactoring a variable name that is also reserved in many programming languages?

Comment: It happens with any variable name. I'm glad to see that this is off behaviour though. It's probably something particular to my project setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the field you want rename, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> and the inline rename refactoring will start. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> again, and the rename refactoring dialog will appear. Here you have 2 checkbox settings:
`search in comments and strings` and `search for text occurrences`, disable those and it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Pressing shift-f6 the second time to get the expanded dialog was the key.

Comment: @Klaus: yes ! Just changed it once with those boxes unchecked, it will remember (if you haven't really refactored with 2 x Shift+F6, it wont remember, even if you did uncheck  those boxes )

Comment: Ok, this answer works, it's a pretty dangerous refactor that IDEA provided.